# Blender Scripting: Copied Objects not enabled Rigidbody active

Tags: python, scripting, physics, rigid-body-simulation

[Pre Bug report checking] {Using Blender 2.79 Scripting}

I tried to copy some object, to multiple places and discovered the Rigidbody Active settings did not animate during playback.
The settings did get copied but the selected color was orange not green (which of course symbolizes Active Ridgedbody is enabled).

When I used the hidden Report window text trick to try to transfer the code to my script (via what the GUI is doing) I discovered another deeply concerning issue.

It seems there is no function to assign the object easily and one has to think in a UI way to code it?! [horrors]

```
ctx.scene.objects.active = object
bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()
```

This function `object_add` should take the list of objects to assign not need to make each object active first. [super bad]

First problem is the copy failed, second problem the way to activate it is junior patch at best (especially since it maybe resets settings etc).

I must be missing some kind of way to add objects to the scenes rigidbody cache resolver list or something similar. Next problem is if that's true the report window is really not much help to devs/scripting because it's all coded in a GUI-centric way?! To only call functions on the active object or pre selection etc. seems an unfortunate undersight, when an argument to the target objects is my expectation here it's still secondarily to the notion of maybe better if there is a function that is inherited from a subclass level like `Object` or `Mesh`. Then one would just call the `objects.rigidbody.add()` function or something or maybe `objects.ridgedbody = new Rigedbody()` and the system would look for that on frame zero on all objects and add it to the solver's list/cache etc.

This would make the problem of the resolver disconnect that must occur in rigidbody `object_add` function obsolete. I would even just fill the default settings in if a none null rigidbody value was discovered (my just-in-time never fail way of thinking (must be the typeless JS coder in me)).

Anyway maybe someone could explain the best way to add a copied object to the solver and make it active because even though the values in the panel are set and copied it's clearly not been activated and showing a green highlighted outline (Bug?). Really though I'd like to see some serious discussion in the tracker on doing something fundamental better as I can see this is a big mess that needs taking by the horns. Still it could be simple to just add an object list argument to what I imagine are many functions only suppose to work on some GUI selected (or active) items. (Again, sorry, but it feels terminally sickly to me)

~

*In the end if it's not easy to find from the docs we have another considerable bigger problem, which leads to one guy helping online with super lowlevel stuff like this. "How do I add to the solver what was copied?" or documentation sections for coders if you copy call add solver but then a overridden copy function would do that so it seems maybe the bug is in the copy of rigidbody then?).*

*Finally I just want to say this is also about encourage and motivating Blender devs to consider major improvements over the way the code is designed. Meaning this is another way of thinking to incorporate in many areas in the future I guess but it's seems they're obviously better methodologies to me, that should get addressed if not long ago, than with high priority asap*

Comment: Working on the active or selected objects is how operators work.  The _context / operator_ paradigm has been with blender since 2.5. IIRC there was a LOT of whinging then, to go back to 2.49b (and prior) methods where the arguments were passed.   Questions:  How are you copying the object?  why not use `bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='ACTIVE')` to add multiple objects (`context.selected_objects`)  as active, to the rigid body world. btw, suggest not using the `object` keyword as a variable (python is forgiving, still not a good idea)

Comment: Thanks fro the comments. I won't bother anyone more with this then. I did change it to 'object' for readability but had ob or obj typically originally. Fact is it's wrong so a bad decision was made then because when I make a copy calling on children loop and still no active objects even though they show the values on?,,, It doesn't animate or turn green without adding each one as posted above.

Comment: I suggest removing parts of the question that relate to messages to developers or your concerns that this is not how the api should be - this isn't the right place for that discussion and it is making your question longer and more complex than I think it needs to be.